# build a CNN specifically trained for predicting numerical value in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

i am trying to run a cnn model to predict face attractiveness (numeric output) based on solely a person's image as input. I have the folder with images and the the database of ratings (1-7) of each face. Database is chicago face database and alternative 10k US Adult Faces Database. However i am struggling to run it and all i find about cnns are for classification problems (predicting cats or dogs with already labeled dataset). Also i am having problems reading the images as CFD images are 2444*1718 and i get an error "cannot allocate vector of size 96.1 Mb". I have 4gb RAM and use 64gui R and did memory.limit(size=56000), even memory.limit(size=560000). Upon the second size i have managed to read 130 images (100 training, 30 testing). Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: seeing Yaoshiang's answer i specify that the ratings are not only 1,2,...,7 but because its the average score of 12 individuals, they are decimals:

```
memory.limit() ## Checking the set limit
```

[1] 4055

```
memory.limit(size=560000)
summary(CFDNEW_all_males$Attractive)
```

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
1.520   2.699   3.160   3.218   3.735   5.071

```
train_image_files_path <- "/Users/e-mashine/Documents/block 5/pictures cfd/training"
test_image_files_path <- "/Users/e-mashine/Documents/block 5/pictures cfd/testing"
train_files <- list.files(path = train_image_files_path, pattern = "*.jpg", full.names=TRUE)
test_files <- list.files(path = test_image_files_path, pattern = "*.jpg", full.names=TRUE)
train_cnn <- lapply(train_files[1:102], readImage) # if i try the whole train and test sets (305 and 102 images respectively) i get this error :
```

error: cannot allocate vector of size 96.1 mb

```
test_cnn <- lapply(test_files[1:31], readImage)
str(train_cnn)
```

List of 102
$ :Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
.. ..@ .Data    : num [1:2444, 1:1718, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..@ colormode: int 2
$ :Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
.. ..@ .Data    : num [1:2444, 1:1718, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..@ colormode: int 2
$ :Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
.. ..@ .Data    : num [1:2444, 1:1718, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..@ colormode: int 2
$ :Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
.. ..@ .Data    : num [1:2444, 1:1718, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
.. ..@ colormode: int 2

```
foreach(i=1:102) %do% {train_cnn[[i]] <- resize(train_cnn[[i]],150,150)}
```

Error in { : task 1 failed - "Expecting a four-dimensional array"

```
dim(train_cnn[[1]])
```

[1] 2444 1718    3

```
width(train_cnn[[1]])
```

[1] 2444

```
height(train_cnn[[1]])
```

[1] 1718

```
depth(train_cnn[[1]])
```

[1] 3

```
spectrum(train_cnn[[1]])
```

[1] NA

from what i read it should be of 2444 width, 1718 height, 1 depth and 3 spectrum but i dont know why is like this... could it be because typeof(train_cnn[[1]]) is double and not integer?

Comment: Could you please share some code ?

Comment: @Cristi i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Deep learning is generally used for classification type problems, not regression. But the capability exists (and is used for example in object detection).

All you have to do is make your final output a sigmoid. That will generate a 0,1 output, exclusive. Then scale it to to the range (-0.5, 6.5) (***), then use MSE loss. The final prediction can be a standard rounding operation.

(***) the range is important. In other settings, one might encode your predictions as being 0,1,2,...,6, and therefore scale sigmoid to the range (0.0, 6.0). But if you do that, you'll make it harder (in fact impossible) for the model to predict the 6 class (your seventh class).

Your memory issues are common - it's likely not that specific allocation that's causing the problem, the issue is that a previous memory allocation was too large, likely due to broadcasting. Just print out the sizes of your model and tensors until you find the offending tensor. It's probably an accidental broadcast because you got your shapes shifted.